# Can't make sense of this piece of java code

Tags: java

I'm working on a legacy system, and i ran into this piece of code that i can't make sense of.

```
String note = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(
                message.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""),
               "UTF-8").replace("%0D%0A", "<br>"), "UTF-8");
```

What does this do, and why is it being encoded and then again decoded.
FYI: This "message" is appended to an email which is sent.

Comment: It looks like the author didn't know about `\r\n`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: No, that is not redundant.

Comment: Looks like an attempt to strip HTML tags, then replace CRLF with line break tag. This is really sketchy... if the input comes from an untrusted source, better to sanitize it with [AntiSamy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project) or something similar.

Comment: You shoud probably refer to this article on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998506/text-file-with-0d-0d-0a-line-breaks

Comment: @RealSkeptic, nope, given the text `<mu>xyz<foo>` the pattern `<.*?>` would match `<mu>` where `<.*>` would match the entire input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st replace to enter is replacing `CRLF` (carret return and line feed symbols) with `<br>` tag. 
2nd replaceAll removes all tags (like `<tag>`).

That UTF-8 is the charset encoding used to decode/encode raw bytes into actual characters. WWWC (World wide Web Consorcium) [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars) that UTF-8 should be used.

Answer (score 0):

From the coding perspective, break down to the following code may help to understand better:

```
    String updatedMessage = message.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
System.out.println(updatedMessage );

    String encodedMessage = URLEncoder.encode(updatedMessage ,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(encodedMessage );

    String updatedEncodedMessage = encodedMessage .replace("%0D%0A", "<br>");
System.out.println(updatedEncodedMessage );

    String note = URLDecoder.decode(updatedEncodedMessage ,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(note );
```

There is no regex involved, just some string replacement.