# Iterating the keys from a javascript hashmap gives empty string for last element

Tags: javascript, typescript, hashmap, iteration

I need the keys from a javascript/typescript hash map in an array. I use the Map.Keys() method, and iterate the keys to populate the an array called:searchTerms. For some reason, the last value in the array is always an empty string.

When I view the hashMap in the debugger, I see exactly what I expect; keys of type string, and values of an array of strings, with no empty keys.

```
public setSearchTerms(searchMap: Map<string, Array<string>>) {
        if(searchMap && searchMap.size) {
            let myKeys = myMap.keys();
            this.searchTerms = [...myKeys];

           /*
            for(let k of myKeys) {
                if(k.length > 0) {
                    this.searchTerms.push(k);
                }
            }
            */
        }
    }
```

When I run the code as is, the searchTerms Array has all the keys from the map, plus an empty string. Using the for-of loop (Currently comment out) also puts in the empty string, but I put in the length check which resolve the issue. I just want to understand where the empty string comes from. I can make it work, but it's bugging me that I can't figure out where the empty string comes from.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this, I feel like there's something else in your code that's interfering with this

Comment: I have to agree with @Aplet123

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I'll look into my hashMap some more. I populate the hashmap with csv data from FileReader.readAsText() so maybe somewhere upstream (Perhaps a hidden \n). Thank you both for looking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it IS an `cr/lf` issue. Did a `hexdump` of the source file and there is an extra `0a0d` at the end. Found a previous stack post that explained it. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998506/text-file-with-0d-0d-0a-line-breaks)